# How to set a WPF usercontrol property from XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I'm trying to set the fill property of several instances of the same usercontrol from XAML in order to distinguish them. I'm using a dependency property in the C# codebehind of the control and referring to that in the XAML when I instantiate the control. Here's a simplified example of what I've tried, first the XAML of the user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="RectangleFillUserControlTest.RectangleFillTest"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="150">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle x:Name="rect" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now the codebehind:

```
namespace RectangleFillUserControlTest
{
    public partial class RectangleFillTest : UserControl
    {
        SolidColorBrush fillBrush;

        public static readonly DependencyProperty FillColourProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
            ("FillColour", typeof(string), typeof(RectangleFillTest), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

        public string FillColour
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(FillColourProperty); }

            set
            {
                SetValue(FillColourProperty, value);
                if (value == "red") fillBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                else fillBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                rect.Fill = fillBrush;
            }
        }

        public RectangleFillTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I instantiate the control in the main window and try to set the fill colour to red:

```
<Window x:Class="RectangleFillUserControlTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RectangleFillUserControlTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Background="#FF1D2CC3">
        <local:RectangleFillTest FillColour="red"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But the rectangle remains unfilled, even when I run the project. Can anyone help please?

Cheers,

Tim

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will explain why is is not working and how to solve.

1.- A Dependency Property is only called when the usercontrol has that dependency property in the visual tree.

In case you want to do in that way, you need to add for instance :

```
new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, ValueChanged));
```

and there change the value:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FillColourProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
        ("FillColour", typeof(string), typeof(RectangleFillTest), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, ValueChanged));

    private static void ValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = d as RectangleFillTest;
        var fillBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
        if (control.FillColour == "red")
            fillBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        else
            fillBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        control.rect.Fill = fillBrush;
    }

    public string FillColour
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(FillColourProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(FillColourProperty, value);

        }
    }
```

That is explicit for your logic, in case you need a more generic code for any color, etc using binding the property to the rectangle, just tell me.

Comment: After been searching for a few hours this finally did the trick for me. Thanks a lot for pointing out the ValueChanged callback!

Answer (score 9):

There are two things wrong with your dependency property.

First, its type should be `Brush`, not string, because that is the type used by properties of WPF controls like `Shape.Fill` or `Control.Background`. WPF provides automatic type conversion from strings like "Red" or "#FFFF0000" in XAML to type Brush.

Second, you should not have anything else than a call to `SetValue` in the setter method of the CLR wrapper. The reason is explained in the [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx) article on MSDN:

> Because the current WPF implementation of the XAML processor behavior
>   for property setting bypasses the wrappers entirely, you should not
>   put any additional logic into the set definitions of the wrapper for
>   your custom dependency property. If you put such logic in the set
>   definition, then the logic will not be executed when the property is
>   set in XAML rather than in code.

So your dependency property declaration should look like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FillBrushProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "FillBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(RectangleFillTest));

public Brush FillBrush
{
    get { return (Brush)GetValue(FillBrushProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FillBrushProperty, value); }
}
```

To react to property changes, you would now register a PropertyChangedCallback with property metadata. But you don't need to do that here, because you could simply bind the property in the UserControl's XAML like this:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding FillBrush,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks for the quality explanation, excellent code, also the binding info. Cue more desperate questions on how to bind which to what, coming soon.

Comment: Hello Clemens, I tried both solutions and both completely solved my problem. I'm not sure of the etiquette of which answer to accept in that case so I accepted the one from Juan, who would benefit more from the extra rep. Hope this is OK. Thanks again for your time and effort.

Comment: You should accept the answer that helped you most and that you consider the best one. Accepting an answer just because you think the author could benefit from the reputation points is wrong and may be misleading to others.

Comment: OK, I accepted Juan's answer because it didn't mean delving into binding. Yours may be the better answer but I'm not really qualified to judge, besides I'm British so don't like to upset people by saying I prefer one to the other. Hope this clears up any confusion, and also hope to benefit again from your help in the near future. Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your Dependency Property to the Fill property of your Rectangle in the xaml of your UserControl. You'll have Something like this :

```
<Rectangle x:Name="rect" Fill="{Binding FillColour, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=RectangleFillTest}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150"/>
```

Also, in your dependency property, it's type should be Brush, and not String.